# HttpWebRequest in background thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I'd like to execute an `HttpWebRequest` in a separate thread.

For example I have:

```
public string GetPage(string url)
{
    string html = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
    return html;
}
```

How would I run this in a separate thread without much hassle?

I have tried starting a simple thread but I have no idea how to return the HTML.

Comment: You can't "return" the result without blocking the current thread; which really kinda defeats the purpose of another thread.

Comment: What are you doing with the result? Any reason this can't be put on a background thread as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it "without much hassle", use c# 5.0

```
public async void DoWork(string url)
{
    string page = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    //Caller thread will not be blocked but you will be able to
    //continue your work at this point after BG thread 
    //(executing "DownloadStringTaskAsync") has downloaded the page

}
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the awesome answer. But How can I get the return value?

Comment: What about using a ref or out parameter??

Comment: Ref/out parameters won't help here. The fetching will happen in the background, and your code will continue on. Do whatever processing you need to do on the return value on the background thread as well.

Comment: Technically, this does *not* use a background thread, but it does solve the OP's actual problem (download a string without blocking).

Comment: I know this comment is a little bit late, but I never selected an answer, so I selected this answer because it was well deserved. I was just to stupid to understand it back then. :)

Answer (score 0):

"without much hassle" is unlikely...

Options:

- drop results into some sort of synchronized collection (i.e. [ConcurentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265) ) to build some sort of consumer/producer pair (pass that collection as argument to your call)
- pass some sort of callback "data ready" that will be called when data is there (similar to [DownloadStringCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted%28v=vs.100%29) )
- just process data on that new thread and commit results wherever you need